# Excel VBA and ADODB: retrieve auto identity of row inserted into SQL Server from VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, ado, vba

In a VBA module for Excel.
Using an ADODB.Connection and this connection string:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MARS;Initial Catalog=automation;Trusted_connection=yes;"
```

I want to:

1. INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('Something')
2. Retrieve the auto incremented identity (test.data_id) of the newly inserted row.

Comment: Here the question that help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976593/how-do-i-return-a-new-identity-column-value-from-an-sqlserver-select-statement

Comment: Thanks Hiten0004. I saw that one earlier. I can't get it to work in VBA.

Comment: Your solution was in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim identity as integer
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cn.ConnectionString = "whatever..."
cn.Open
cn.Execute ("INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES ('hello world')")
rs.Open "SELECT @@identity AS NewID", cn
identity = rs.Fields("NewID") 
MsgBox (identity)
```

Comment: Awesome , thanks just what I was looking for , worked like magic

Comment: If you have a connection variable this can be simplified as `identity = cn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity")(0)` without creating a recordset.